# How to create report, where the amounts are cumulated into the next month

Tags: reporting, custom-field

I've been looking at this problem for a while now, and I haven't found a solution on any of the other salesforce forums.

I want to have a report with a column chart, which does the following:

- we select a time period for the dates we want to visualize (done via Filter)
- we select a sales rep we want the data for (done via Filter)
- we group columns by date, so we get a monthly report on the X-axis (used "As of Date" in group columns)
- starting from the first column, we display the Quote Amount of the sales rep
- the next column will have the previous columns value + the actual months Quote Amount, and so on.

This means, that the graph would be ascending at all times (or if there's a month with "0" Quote Amount, that month will be the same as the previous one).

Can this be achieved in the salesforce reporting tool?

Here's the chart in Excel:
[image]

After this is done, I would like to select not only the "Quote Amount", but another field ("Net Amount"), so each months values could be compared by having 2 columns in the chart next to eachother.

Comment: Yes, this can be achievable using custom summary formula in the Summary report. The formula should be using PREVGROUPVAL, refer this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9c1_ErEtCf0